# PayPal payment method with commission

Tags: paypal

I am currently working on a project on which one user can personally send files or documents to other users. If the sender wants he could set a price for the file and the receiver have to pay in order to download that file. I have decided to use PayPal for the payment processes.

Now from each transaction(of money), I want a little commission from the money that the sender gets.

At first I had a idea of receiving all the payments(form the receiver) on my personal account, keep some commissions and transfer the remaining to the sender. But it would make the entire process so difficult and hard to maintain. I have currently read [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/) and I am wandering if that gives you some commission for the transactions or it doesn't?

Ultimately, my question is: Can you get some commissio n(or money) using PayPal payee. (or directly sending the money form sender to receiver)?'

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `payee` does not split off any commission. It is a direct payment between two other accounts.

You could see about requesting access to [Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts), and use that for separate outgoing transactions after receiving full amounts into your own account.

Comment: What if i do according to my first idea? Would it be hard for me?
You have any suggestions?

Comment: It does not split the payment.

Comment: Yea. Can you please tell me, how big companies like Fiverr do this kinds of transaction?

Comment: If they are a PayPal partner they might specify a platform_fee for regular order payments.